# How to find local maximum using wxmaxima

Tags: maxima

I have this; (x)=-(x^3+6*x^2-18*x)/(4*(x^2+2));
Have differentiated and tried to solve for x but get too many answers. 
[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rtou.png)

Comment: How did you solve it, and what result did you get? What is it about the result that seems undesirable?

Answer (score 1):

Use `realroots` to discard complex roots:

```
y:-(x^3+6*x^2-18*x)/(4*(x^2+2));
realroots(diff(y,x)=0),numer;
[x=-1.688117772340774,x=0.8158789575099945]
```

Comment: an explanation as to why that would work helps everyone.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. I thought that `realroots` would only work for a polynomial. Maybe it is looking only at the numerator of the rational function. The documentation for `realroots` doesn't mention anything about that; I guess it would be necessary to look at the code.

Comment: @RobertDodier, I do not know maxima's internals, but possibly this gets converted to a problem with a pair of polynomials. `realroots(x^3+6*x^2-18*x)` which are not in `realroots(4*(x^2+2))`